# Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role. Simple JPA findById

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring and JPA (Hibernate with MySQL) and Lombok also.

Hi have this part of my entities:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "entitya")
public class EntityA  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ea_id")
    Long id;
    ....

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="g_id", nullable=false)
    private Group group;

    ....
}

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "group")
    public class Group implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="g_id")
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="group")
        private List<EntityA> enitiesA = new ArrayList<>();

        ...
    }
```

I implemented also the repository extends JPARepository.
Into my controllers, if I try to retrieve an EntityA by Id I obtain this exception:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mytest.entity.Group.enitiesA, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

For me it's strange because I need to retrieve only the object. I not use some getter methods on this. So, in theory, using the default fetch types, I don't need to have also the group list.

What's wrong?

Comment: you should post your controller code also

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging your object with toString()?

In case it could be an error caused by the @Data annotation.

The generated toString() method contains all fields, so it might call the enitiesA variable, producing the lazy initialization error.

https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/

Answer (score 0):

Likely it's because you're accessing group.enitiesA outside of the transactional boundaries.  If you want to do this, you can eager fetch them by adding eager fetch type to your OneToMany mapping such as

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="group", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

This will load the entire object graph when the parent is loaded.

If you still want to do lazy loading, look to encapsulate all of the calls into the children under the session that loaded the parent.